# ObservableList doesn't update ArrayList

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

For a school assignment, we're working with ObservableList objects from JavaFX (Right?). I've been working on this for over a day now and can't figure it out. The teacher only tells us to 'Google it' so that's no help either..

Basically, we're working on a basic administration application to keep track of people and their families. Where people are member of a family, and a family can have multiple members.

When a person or family is added, they are added to an observableList which *should* then update an ArrayList (So the data can be serialized) and a GUI element. This is where the problem is.

We currently have the following implementation:

```
private List<Persoon> personen;
private List<Gezin> gezinnen;
this.personen = new ArrayList<Persoon>();
this.gezinnen = new ArrayList<Gezin>();

private transient ObservableList<Persoon> observablePersonen;
private transient ObservableList<Gezin> observableGezinnen;
observablePersonen = FXCollections.observableArrayList(personen);
observableGezinnen = FXCollections.observableArrayList(gezinnen);
```

Then when an item is added, we do the following:

```
Persoon p = new Persoon();
observablePersonen.add(p);
observablePersonen.notifyAll();
```

After this when we inspect the 'personen' list, the added object isn't there :(

Are we missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you fail to understand the concept of an `ObservableList`. Whether or not `personen` will be updated is not connected to the fact it's an `ObservableList`, but to whether or not it is backed by `personen`, and in your code, using `observableArrayList`, it isn't. The call to `notifyAll` is irrelevant.

Comment: The other approach (and probably the better one, tbh) to serializing data in JavaFX observable properties and observable collections is to define a custom serialized form via `readObject` and `writeObject` methods, instead of trying to keep double copies of all the lists and properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [`FXCollections.observableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) instead of [`FXCollections.observableArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

As per the documentation of `observableList`:

> Constructs an ObservableList that is backed by the specified list.

So any modification of the observable list will be reported to the backing list. However, in the case of `observableArrayList`:

> Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it.

so this list is not backed by the given list, it just serves as an initial collection.

As a side note, you should not call `notifyAll()`: this method has nothing to do with JavaFX and it relates to waking threads waiting on this object.

Comment: When I do that and add something to the observableList, I get an IllegalMonitorStateException when running the notifyAll() on the observableList.

Comment: @cascer1 see my edit, you should not call notifyAll as this has nothing to do with JavaFX

Answer (score 0):

Sample of how an `ArrayList` can be synced to an `ObservableList`.

```
public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    public static ObservableList<Double> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // add a listener to the ObservableList
        observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Double> c) {
                // c represents the changed element
                System.out.println("Added " + c + " to the Observablelist");
                // we add the last element added to the observable list to the arraylist
                arrayList.add(observableList.get(observableList.size()-1));
                System.out.println("Added " + arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1) + " to the Arraylist");
            }
        });

        observableList.add(5.0);
        observableList.add(7.0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Added { [5.0] added at 0 } to the Observablelist
Added 5.0 to the Arraylist
Added { [7.0] added at 1 } to the Observablelist
Added 7.0 to the Arraylist
```

Comment: You're assuming the *only* changes to the `ObservableList` are adding elements to the end of the list?

Comment: @James_D To be honest, one of the quirks of this assignment is indeed that items are only ever added and never removed.

Comment: For this very simple demonstration - yes. The code should obviously be modified in a way to also handle the removal or addition of elements which are not placed at the end of the list.

Comment: Handling `observableList.addAll(1.0, 2.0, 1.0); observableList.remove(2);` (the latter statement removes the element at index `2`, not the element with value 2) is pretty much impossible, unless you are proposing rebuilding the list every time. The `ListChangeListener.Change` API simply doesn't provide enough functionality to handle all cases.

Comment: @James_D,
The Java 8 ListChangeListener.Change API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) provides support for signaling element addition, permutation, removal, replacement, and update. It seems quite complete. Why do you consider them impossible to handle?

Comment: @JoseTepedino In the example I cited, how would you update the array list to be the same as the observable list, without either rebuilding the whole thing, or iterating through both lists to check changes. There's no way to know from the `Change` object that the second `1.0`, not the first, was the one removed.

Comment: @James_D
That will work if we use ``public static ObservableList<Double> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(arrayList);``.
Please have a look of the comment I've just added, refactoring this code.

Comment: Please notice that ``observableList.remove(2);`` and ``observableList.remove(2.0);`` will lead to different answers, according to the [List API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The ambiguity would only occur if we had a list of Integer objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Once try this code its work for me:**

here `old_list` is type of `ObservableArrayList<CustomType>`

```
//update new changes
old_list.map{
//do your changes
}
val templist=old_list.clone() // make a clone
old_list.clear() //clear old list
old_list.addAll(templist as ObservableArrayList<CustomType>)
```