# MVVM in Java without changing the model (with its business logic)

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, mvvm, fxml

In my business logic model, I use a class with an ArrayList to store Objects of type Content. Everything works perfecty.

However, I have no idea how to bind that model to the ModelView, without making any changes (except for getters/setters) to the model.

**(EDIT:) What I mean by that: All model-related classes cannot be changed to Properties (e.g. String -> SimpleStringProperty)**

Is it possible to implement a MVVM without altering the model (e.g. change ArrayList to ObservableArrayList etc.)?

(Business Logic) Model:

```java
    public class Model {
         UploaderDB uploaderDB = new UploaderDB();
         [...]

         public UploaderDB getUploaderDB() {
              return this.uploaderDB;
         }
    }
```

```java
    public class UploaderDBImpl implements UploaderDB {
        private List<Uploader> uploaderList = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Uploader> getUploaderList() {
             return this.uploaderList;
        }
    }
```

```java
    public class UploaderImpl implements Uploader {
        public String name;

        public String getName() {
             return this.name;
        }
    }
```

ModelView

```java
    public class ViewModel {
        private ObservableList<Uploader> items;

        public ViewModel() {
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(model.getUploaderDB().getUploaderList());
        }
    }
```

View (MainWindow.java as Controller, MainWindow.fxml)

```java
    public class MainWindow {
        @FXML
        private TableView<UploaderDB> uploaderTable;

        @FXML public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources {    
uploaderTable.itemsProperty().bind(modelView.items);
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1100.0"             
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea"         
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.MainWindow">
       <children>
          <VBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="581.0" 
    prefWidth="662.0">
         <children>
    <TableView fx:id="uploaderTable" prefHeight="581.0" prefWidth="396.0" >

               <columns>
                   <TableColumn  prefWidth="180.0" text="Name" >
                       <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="$uploaderName" />
                      </cellValueFactory>
                   </TableColumn>
                   <TableColumn  prefWidth="100.0" text="Uploads" >
                       <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="" />
                       </cellValueFactory>
                   </TableColumn>
            </columns>
                <!--</!-->
            </TableView>
         </children></VBox>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your `List` in the Model you should use `ObservableList` not the `ObservableArrayList`.

See this answer from @Tunaki

[ObservableList doesn't update ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907813/observablelist-doesnt-update-arraylist)

Comment: Thank you! But what I meant: All model-related classes cannot be changed to Properties (e.g. String -> SimpleStringProperty). Is it still possible to use TableView and keep the View and the Model synchronized?